# What is the benefit of implicit performance of a probability of default model?

Tags: model-evaluation, gini, credit-scoring

I have a model which predicts a binary outcome (default/no default).
The discriminatory power of the model is normally quantified with Somers' D which is the same as Gini in the binary context.

[image]

$Gini = 2 \times AUC -1$

AUC is also nicely explained here: [https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc#:~:text=AUC%20stands%20for%20%22Area%20under,to%20(1%2C1)](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc#:%7E:text=AUC%20stands%20for%20%22Area%20under,to%20(1%2C1)).

Now, I am reading some new documentation which distinguishes **implicit** vs **explicit** performance. Explicit is the observed Gini and implicit is the Gini if the observations materialise as predicted. For example an observation has a 10% PD it will default with 10%. Based on the predicted PD outcomes can be simuated. Next, Gini is calculated on those simulated outcomes.

**What is the benefit of knowing the implicit Gini?**

It sounds like a natural upper bound for a good model. Does this make sense?

Comment: What exactly did you read about it and where? Honestly, I hear the term the first time, and googling it does not return any results about the "implicit" or "explicit" Gini.

Comment: Same, I read it in some internal documentation which makes me wonder if it makes any sense whatsoever, but maybe it is a known concept under a different name somewhere.

Comment: It seems like this approach proposes a distribution, samples from that distribution, and then draws conclusion from the samples as if samples drawn from a known distribution give additional insight. I truly cannot understand what is happening with this. Is the idea to get a confidence interval for the Gini value?

Comment: Yes, they are also calculating a confidence interval around the implicit gini, though I do not see this being applied to the explicit gini.